# Split text file by line, platform-independently

Tags: java, encoding

I wanna split a text file by line, so on Windows that would be `text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset); text.split("\r\n", -1)` and on UNIX it's `text.split("\n", -1)`, and `text.split(System.lineSeparator(), -1)` works for both. But what if a file is created on UNIX and copied to Windows or vice versa - how do I best handle those cases? And what would that mean for the file itself - would it be broken if you tried to view it in a text editor like notepad?

Comment: Why don't use `Files.readAllLines()`?

Comment: Why do you want to load the entire file into memory first, before splitting it into lines, when you can read the lines directly from the file using the `readLine()` method of `BufferedReader`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`Files.readAllLines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-). Alternatively [`Files.lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) which will return you a `Stream` of lines.

From the javadoc of `readAllLines`:

> This method recognizes the following as line terminators:
>
> - \u000D followed by \u000A, CARRIAGE RETURN followed by LINE FEED
> - \u000A, LINE FEED
> - \u000D, CARRIAGE RETURN

Copying from one file system to the other doesn't change the content of the file (except you are doing some "special" copying ;-) ).

Answer (score 1):

If you create a file, it will use whatever line separator is native to the platform.

If you then open the file on another platform, the file does not change. If you open a unix file on windows, it doesn't gain the extra `\r` character.

It really depends on the editor as to how it looks, some editors handle things better than others.

As for Java, just use `System.lineSeparator()` if you need to specify the end of line character sequence.

As @Andreas mentioned, you can use `BufferedReader.readLine()` to read a file a line at a time, and it will handle the end of line character sequence in a platform independent manner.